# Visual Studio 2013 - Automatic update link href

Tags: html, visual-studio-2013

I have a CSS-file which is linked to several different webpages.

When I physically move this css file to another folder (or I rename the CSS-file) all referring pages are loosing this link.

What am I missing in VS 2013 so that these references are updated automatically

Answer (score 0):

[Webstorm](https://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/) supports this feature.

If VS13 doesn't support it you may try find and replace.

Comment: Thanks for this, I will check Webstorm ... 
Find / replace is of course a useful workaround but I can not imagine that a great / big application like VS2013 does not support such an essential feature (Dreamweaver had this feature a few years  ago)

Answer (score 0):

I think that you should keep the CSS file in the same directory or the same folder as all your webpages and documents that you are linking to it .That is the rule otherwise it will not work .